# Security of bitsliced AES with a transposition step omitted

Tags: aes, bitslicing

Suppose you take the aes_sub_bytes function intended to operate on 4 aes blocks which were bitsliced to 8 u64's but you omit the bitslicing step beforehand. As a result you apply the sbox to the incorrect bits. But nevertheless the sbox is applied to all bits.

Do the security properties of AES change at all? You are no longer applying the sbox as neatly as intended (individual bytes on 4x4 byte grid), but it is still messily applied.

So to summarize, you pointer cast 512 bits of aes into 8 u64's and feed them into a bunch of XORs and and ANDs (which are intended to implement the sbox on bitsliced aes but you did not do the bitslicing step). Do you get the same confusion out of this sub_bytes step as you would with the original cipher? Ignoring potential endianness compatibility problems if any.

Let's assume all the other AES steps are performed correctly as AES is designed.

This may lead to the 4 AES blocks becoming entangled with each other through the s-box. This is fine as they will always be together.

Comment: I suggest changing the title to: _security of bitsliced AES with a transposition step omitted_. "Portable" is not descriptive (is it there because it's hard to make a fast and portable transposition?). I also suggest removing the "focus on the S-box", because the question is about "security properties of AES" and the transposition step that's removed can't be specific to the S-boxes. Please explain the outer structure assumed for the security analysis. It seems at least 4 AES 128-bit blocks are involved in the bitslicing considered, to get 64 S-boxes active.

Comment: A normal bitsliced implementation of aes_sub_bytes with 64-bit words has eight 64-bit inputs and eight 64-bit outputs, make that $g$ on the set $(\{0,1\}^{64})^8$. It handles 4 simultaneous AES operations, since there are 16 S-boxes per round, and 64/16=4. I see no way to reduce that 4 without a drastic speed loss. Is it run 4 AES instances normally, except that for aes_sub_bytes we apply $g$? Obvious fact: we get a 512-bit block cipher.